# How can I automatically deploy static HTML repo to Azure when the full repo overwrites (deletes) workflows

Tags: azure, github, azure-web-app-service

I'm experimenting with Publii in order to generate static websites.
They have an option to sync your website, which pushes the "public/rendered" website to the repository.

This however, causes the workflow files to be removed and removes automatic deployment to my azure static web apps.

I don't foresee any possibility right now to tweak Publii to avoid overwriting everything.
What is the cleanest solution to automatically deploy a static html repo, knowing that workflow files will be removed every time?

1. Publish / sync website from Publii to Github
2. Files get overwritten and workflow files (actions) are removed.

Comment: `--skip-worktree` is useful when you instruct git not to touch a specific file ever because developers should change it.

Answer (score 0):

***Approach 1)***

Create separate repository for your Source code project, Build and Deploy your source code project from the same repository. And create deployment via your Source code project repository which will contain your deployment history. And enablke Continous integration, Where the github action pipeline will be triggered when any changes are made to the source code repository, This will render the new changes.

***Approach 2)***

After pulling the changes from the source code repository, Make sure you, ***Install and create static website from Pubii and build it with the Github Action yml pipeline below:-***

*Github Action workflow:-*

```yaml
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, closed]
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build_and_deploy_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build and Deploy Job
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          submodules: true
          lfs: false
      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: |
          sudo apt-get update
          sudo apt-get install -y libnotify4
      - name: Install Publii
        run: |
          wget https://cdn.getpublii.com/Publii-0.45.2.deb
          sudo dpkg -i Publii-0.45.2.deb
      - name: Add Publii to PATH
        run: |
          PUB_PATH=$(find /usr -name Publii | head -n 1)
          if [ -n "$PUB_PATH" ]; then
            echo "export PATH=\"$PUB_PATH:\$PATH\"" >> $HOME/.bashrc
            source $HOME/.bashrc
          else
            echo "Publii not found."
          fi
      - name: Build Website
        run: |
          publii build
      - name: Deploy Website
        id: builddeploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_HAPPY_MUSHROOM_022EF1703 }}
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} 
          action: "upload"
          app_location: "build"
```

[image]